# MVC3 C# Beginner in Twitterizer: How to logOn user via Twitter and get some user information?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, twitterizer

I downloaded Twitterizer, read documentation, downloaded the samples but as I'm working with MVC3, I'm a little bit lost about how to write the code. Could someone guide me posting code samples on how to logIn an user in my system using Twitter and get some information as full name, birthdate, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just move to [TweetSharp](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp), much easier to understand if you are beginner with OAuth. This video tutorial saved my day http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A6AVn-E3TwY

Comment: TweetSharp is no longer actively maintained by it's authors (as is plainly stated on their github site) and is likely to become out of sync with the Twitter API.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example application following the video you posted, but using Twitterizer.

http://www.twitterizer.net/files/twitterizer-mvc3-login-example.zip

Comment: Hey Ricky, the zip seems to be corrupt... is there another link to it?

Comment: I just downloaded it and extracted it without any issues. Can you try again?

Comment: I tried it from two different computers and the result is always the same: `twitterizer-mvc3-login-example.zip: The archive is corrupt twitterizer-mvc3-login-example.zip: The archive is corrupt
twitterizer-mvc3-login-example.zip: CRC failed in twitterizer-mvc3-login-example\packagesEntityFramework.4.1.10331.0.nupkg. The file is corrupt twitterizer-mvc3-login-example.zip: The archive is corrupt`

Comment: I also tried using multiple browsers (Firefox, Chrome, etc), but the problem persists.

Comment: ... and this is why we should keep copies of all of our source code. /facepalm

Comment: I could recreate that, but I've already written up a blog post about authorizing with MVC3: http://www.twitterizer.net/797/sign-on-with-twitter-in-mvc3/

Comment: thanks! Great job on the article! I'm bookmarking it for sure!