# Twitterizer- The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitterizer

I'm following Ricky's [Twitterizer example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003959/mvc3-c-sharp-beginner-in-twitterizer-how-to-logon-user-via-twitter-and-get-some/8039457#8039457) (with some modifications on my end), but I'm getting a "401 Unauthorized" exception when I try to send the authentication request:

```
{Twitterizer.TwitterizerException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Twitterizer.WebRequestBuilder.ExecuteRequest()
   at Twitterizer.OAuthUtility.GetRequestToken(String consumerKey, String consumerSecret, String callbackAddress)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Twitterizer.OAuthUtility.GetRequestToken(String consumerKey, String consumerSecret, String callbackAddress)
   at MyProject.Controllers.AccountController.Authenticate(String oauthToken, String oauthVerifier, String returnUrl) in C:\path\to\my\website\Controllers\AccountController.cs:line 78}
```

I have private member variables which hold my consumer key and consumer secret:

```
// I obtain my consumer key and the consumer secret from the web config
private static readonly string _twitterConsumerKey = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwitterConsumerKey"];
private static readonly string _twitterConsumerSecret = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwitterConsumerSecret"];
```

And I also have a controller that handles the login:

```
// GET: Account/Logon/
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn(string returnUrl)
{
    return Authenticate(string.Empty, string.Empty, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]));
}

//private ActionResult 
private ActionResult Authenticate(string oauthToken, string oauthVerifier, string returnUrl)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(oauthToken) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(oauthVerifier))
    {
        UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(this.Request.Url);
        builder.Query = string.Concat(
            builder.Query,
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(builder.Query) ? string.Empty : "&",
            "returnUrl=",
            returnUrl);

        try
        {
            string token = OAuthUtility.GetRequestToken(
                _twitterConsumerKey,
                _twitterConsumerSecret,
                builder.ToString()).Token; // <-- Throws the exception

            return Redirect(OAuthUtility.BuildAuthorizationUri(token, true).ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ViewBag.Error = e.ToString(); // 401 Unauthorized
            return View();
        }
    }

    OAuthTokenResponse tokens = OAuthUtility.GetAccessToken(
        _twitterConsumerSecret, 
        _twitterConsumerSecret,
        oauthToken,
        oauthVerifier);

    // Save the user details and set the authentication (cookie)
    // ...
    // ...
    // ...

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
        return Redirect("/");
    else
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
```

Note that I've removed some of the code that doesn't pertain to the error. The above code alone results in the exception. One thing to note is that my `returnUrl` is empty (although the same thing happens if I provide a `returnUrl` too); everything else seems fine. The `HttpWebRequest` looks like this:

```
Address = {https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token?oauth_callback=http://localhost:24465/Account/LogOn?returnUrl=}
```

Any ideas on what may be causing this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Login to dev.twitter.com and double check that your application is a web application. In order to be a web application, you MUST supply a callback url there, even though you're going to provide a 'real' callback at runtime.

FYI, you cannot supply 'localhost' for the registered callback url, but you can use 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Ah, gotcha! Thanks Ricky, I didn't have my application set up as a web application... I'll make the changes and see if I can get it to run correctly. P.S. Does this mean that my desktop service will no longer be able to use the same oath tokens?

Comment: Your desktop application can use your website's consumer token: give "oob" as your callback url at runtime and twitter will use pin-based authentication.

Comment: Yes yes yes!  This was it.  I hadn't specified my callback URL on the twitter site. +1

Comment: me too getting the same error:The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. Any idea? deployed on production but still throws error. Help?