# to get twitter followers count to my web application Asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitterizer

I have to get twitter followers count by using REST API v1.1 by asp.net and c#.i got credentials and tried but getting 401 exception.i tried using twitterizer.

Comment: Post the code that you're using that's getting the exception so we can help you better.

Comment: You might find answer to your problem from here [Twitterizer- The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9085370/twitterizer-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-401-unauthorized)